# Set Filter Dropdown filter style [Tabulator 5.4]

Tags: tabulator

Looking for some assistance on the correct CSS override to change the font in the header filter dropdown list and the value that remains in the filter text field.

[image]

I have tried the following in my custom CSS file:

```
.tabulator .tabulator-header-filter {
    font-size: 7.5pt;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to stick, even after a hard refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tabulator-edit-list` or `tabulator-edit-list-item` classes to style the list. you don't need to use the `.tabulator` selector first because the lists are appended to the document body not the table.

A full list of classes can be found in the documentation:
https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/style#css-menu